# Collapsing javascript code in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I’m looking for equivalent functionality to C# regions in javascript

C# syntax

```
#region RegionName

public static void MyFunction()
{
    [mycode]
}

#endregion
```

This allows me to “collapse” my code in my .js file with Visual Studio and make it a little more manageable.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: This question has the correct method for supporting code collapse in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921628/how-to-implement-regions-in-javascript

Comment: Why not? ````(function /* RegionName */ () { ... })();````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://blog.devarchive.net/2008/04/using-region-directive-with-javascript.html), which implements the #region directives in js files using macros.

Comment: Microsoft now has an extension for VS2010 that provides this functionality (see my answer below for link).

Comment: They took macros out of VS 2012. (Great idea, right?) Any good solutions for VS 2012?

Answer (score 53):

If it need for collapse the java script code then you may select the code and press

Ctrl + M + H

It will collapse the selected code.

Comment: +1 since this doesn't use any plugins.

Comment: Writing this on a post-it note right now!

Comment: How do you remove this collapsible area?

Comment: To remove the collapsible area: CTRL + M, CTRL + U

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s.aspx

Comment: how to add comment in that region currently it show like [...]

Answer (score 17):

Microsoft now has an extension for VS2010 that provides this functionality:

[JScript Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed?SRC=VSIDE)

Comment: Not working for community version.. found it in install log after installation failure..

Answer (score 13):

This feature can be installed in Visual Studio 2012 with the help of Web Essentials plugin.

**EDIT:**

To do an actual region you can use:

```
//#region MyRegion
function Example() {

}
//#endregion
```

The plugin can be downloaded here: 
[Web Essentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6), [Web Essentials for 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f)

Comment: Can you share the syntax for this? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: When you do something like:
`function DoThis()
{ \\stuff  }`

VS2012 should automatically place +/- icon next to it and allow you to expand/collapse the function just like your div's

Comment: Worked fine...love this... Any shortcut to collapse these regions it would be a great help..??!!

Answer (score 5):

For Visual Studio 2012, you can use this extension:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4be701d8-af03-40a4-8cdc-d2add5cde46c

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript outlining extension for VS 2010 here http://jsoutlining.codeplex.com/documentation it works great for me

Answer (score 1):

This is the best one (I've tried them all):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0696ad60-1c68-4b2a-9646-4b5f4f8f2e06/view/Discussions/1